# Parabolic dish focus microwave into mouth of feedhorn, how can wavefront be in phase

Tags: rf

I have a parabolic dish 80cm, offset feedhorn, so section of parabola.
Fix 1cm mirror squares at centre and 4  points near edge. 
Sunlight brought to common overlapping point at feedhorn.
 Distance further edge to horn mouth 73cm,
 distance centre to horn mouth 60cm,
 distance lower edge to horn mouth 52cm.

I have made telescope mirrors, the parabolic shape ensures a parallel wavefront is focussed to a point. The curve is so shallow in comparison, the software does all the correction calculations. It never occurred to me the geometry would seem to introduce a wavefront 'phase' error.
At 12 GHz, wavelength is about 3cm.

Have I missed something with my understanding here?
Or is this dish totally warped out of correct shape?

Comment: There is nothing in your profile to indicate that English is not your first language but you are not writing proper sentences - there are words missing in most of them - and it makes it very difficult to read and understand. A diagram would help.

Answer (score 2):

If the feedhorn is in the **focus** of the parabola then
waves reflected at **any** point of the parabola are in phase by definition.

The parabola (in this case *paraboloid of revolution* to be exact) is defined as the locus of points such that sum of distance from focus to any point on parabola and distance from such point to a plane perpendicular to beam axis is **constant**.

If the distances are constant (i.e. equal for any point of refelection on the parabola) then phases also must be equal.

See [definition of parabola as locus of points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parabola#Definition_of_a_parabola_as_locus_of_points).

Answer (score 0):

Realisation dawns, the wavefront has already travelled further by the time it reaches the lower edge of the dish.
And same for the rest of the dish.
And therefore the phase relationship of the original signal is retained.